# AWS DMS SQL Server to s3 parquet - change-data-type transformation rule and 'Parquet type not supported: INT32 (UINT_8)'

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-dms

We use AWS DMS to dump SQL Server DBs into S3 as parquet files. Idea is to run some analytics with spark over parquets. When a full load is complete then it's not possible to read parquets since they have `UINT` fields in the schema. Spark declines to read them with `Parquet type not supported: INT32 (UINT_8)`. We use transformation rules to overwrite data type of `UINT` columns. But it looks like they are not picked up by DMS engine. Why?

There are number of rules like "convert unit to int" see below (mind UINT1 is 1 byte unsigned [DMS DataTypes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Reference.DataTypes.html)):

```
{
  "rule-type": "transformation",
  "rule-id": "7",
  "rule-name": "uintToInt",
  "rule-action": "change-data-type",
  "rule-target": "column",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": "%",
    "table-name": "%",
    "column-name": "%",
    "data-type": "uint1"
  },
  "data-type": {
    "type": "int4"
  }
}
```

S3 `DataFormat=parquet;ParquetVersion=parquet_2_0` and DMS Engine version is `3.3.2`

However still getting parquet schemas with uint. See below:

```
id: int32
name: string
value: string
status: uint8
```

Attempt to read such parquet using spark gives me

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Parquet type not supported: INT32 (UINT_8);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetToSparkSchemaConverter.typeNotSupported$1(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetToSparkSchemaConverter.convertPrimitiveField(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:136)
```

Why the DMS transformation rule is not triggered?

Comment: Is it limitation I hit? `Changes to the source table structure during full load are not supported` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html

Comment: Did you figure out how to make this work? Thank you.

Comment: @Anton are you still facing this issue? I used the solution proposed below and it worked (I applied the changed to all schemas-%):  
        {
          "rule-type": "transformation",
          "rule-id": "2",
          "rule-name": "uint1-to-int4",
          "rule-action": "change-data-type",
          "rule-target": "column",
          "object-locator": {
              "schema-name": "%",
              "table-name": "%",
              "column-name": "%",
              "data-type": "uint1"
          },
          "data-type": {
              "type": "int1"
          }
        }

Comment: @dp6000, I didn't try it since DMS 3.3.2, we ditch DMS in favor of other solution

Answer (score 4):

Transforming the data directly from **UINT** to **INT** on DMS fixes this issue.
Your mapping rules should look like:

```
{
"rules": [
    ...
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "2",
        "rule-name": "unit1-to-int1",
        "rule-action": "change-data-type",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "schema",
            "table-name": "%",
            "column-name": "%",
            "data-type": "uint1"
        },
        "data-type": {
            "type": "int1"
        }
    },
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "3",
        "rule-name": "unit2-to-int2",
        "rule-action": "change-data-type",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "schema",
            "table-name": "%",
            "column-name": "%",
            "data-type": "uint2"
        },
        "data-type": {
            "type": "int2"
        }
    },
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "4",
        "rule-name": "unit4-to-int4",
        "rule-action": "change-data-type",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "schema",
            "table-name": "%",
            "column-name": "%",
            "data-type": "uint4"
        },
        "data-type": {
            "type": "int4"
        }
    },
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "5",
        "rule-name": "unit8-to-int8",
        "rule-action": "change-data-type",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "schema",
            "table-name": "%",
            "column-name": "%",
            "data-type": "uint8"
        },
        "data-type": {
            "type": "int8"
        }
    }
]}
```

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations

Comment: Can you share the table schemas you are trying to migrate and your mapping rules?

Comment: I have columns of smallint type in SQL Server DB. I tried all kind of combinations to convert intX to uintX (please check example in the question) but it looks like it ignores it. As I mentioned about could be I hit this limitation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html `Changes to the source table structure during full load are not supported`. BTW. you example converts uint to int, doesnt it? I need other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get the transformation working on the parquet files was by specifying the exact column to transform. So for example:

```
{
   "rules": [
   ...
   {
    "rule-type": "transformation",
    "rule-id": "2",
    "rule-name": "unit1-to-int1",
    "rule-action": "change-data-type",
    "rule-target": "column",
    "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "acessa",
        "table-name": "<table_name>",
        "column-name": "<column_name>"
    },
    "data-type": {
        "type": "int1"
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

Using the wildcard % for the column name in the object locator just wasn't working

Comment: Thanks, however I have 6K tables, not really practical to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select specific columns and convert all UINTS to INTS there is no way around specifically naming columns you want to convert. If you do a wildcard data-type conversion it will include override you column selections and include all columns.

Comment: Thanks, however I have 6K tables, not really practical to do it this way